# Express response status 400 change to 503

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-codes

I'm using Express, and I want to send `response` status code 400`. The morgan says that I responsed with status 400`, but I get `503` in browser.

```js
router.get('/counselor/field', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (!req.query.field) {
            res.status(400);
            return res.send('why');
        }
```

[What I get in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YRBc.png)

But when I change status code to else than 400, it works fine.
if I send 401, browser receive 401.

```js
router.get('/counselor/field', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (!req.query.field) {
            res.status(401);
            return res.send('why');
        }
```

[401 response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw2js.png)
I can't understand why only status code 400 change to 503. here is my modules.

```js
const http =require('http');
const express = require("express");
const  wsServer = require ("./socket.js");
const validator = require('validator');
const cors = require('cors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const passport= require('passport');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const hpp = require('hpp');
const helmet = require('helmet');

const {sequelize} = require('./models');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const passportConfig = require('./passport');

const app = express();
dotenv.config();
passportConfig();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT||3000);

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET));

app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
    }
}));
```

Comment: Do you talk directly with your node.js app or is there a webserver/reverse proxy between the client and the app?

Comment: @Marc I tried on pure Javascript and Postman, so I assume there is no proxy on front. On app, I use 'goormIDE' to publish , which is korean Cloud Service. It could be the problem. I should find out whether it affects the status code. thx for comment.